How can I pass a region parameter for MinIO in ABP?
I am trying like this:
Configure<AbpBlobStoringOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Containers.ConfigureDefault(container =>
    {
        container.UseMinio(minio =>
        {
            minio.EndPoint = configuration["MinioOptions:Endpoint"];
            minio.AccessKey = configuration["MinioOptions:AccessKey"];
            minio.SecretKey = configuration["MinioOptions:SecretKey"];
            minio.WithSSL = bool.Parse(configuration["MinioOptions:UseSSL"]);
            minio.BucketName = configuration["MinioOptions:BucketName"];
            minio.CreateBucketIfNotExists = false;
        });
        container.SetConfiguration("Minio.Region", configuration["MinioOptions:Region"]);
    });
});

but I am getting an error:
Minio.Exceptions.UnexpectedMinioException:
'MinIO API responded with message=The authorization header is malformed; the region is wrong; expecting 'ank1'.'
How can I solve this problem?
Best Regards
